# supermicro servers - ipmi / nagios disk monitoring

Tags: nagios, ipmi, supermicro

I have several machines from this manufacturer in my group. I'm looking for a method / process to monitor disk health. IPMI doesn't seem to offer anything beyond fan speed and CPU temperature.

Has anyone got a method to incorporate disk status into Nagios for machines of this ilk?

Comment: With non-RAID controllers, use `smartmontools` and the appropriate management software in case of hardware RAID, e.g. `tw_cli`, together with a Nagios plugin supporting this tool.

Comment: These aren't RAID. Ended up using `smartd` (smartmontools) and `check_ide_smart`. Kudos to @sven. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the downside of systems that aren't fully integrated like HP (ILO) and Dell (DRAC)... Your IPMI will only give you the bare minimum of health information about the Supermicro server.

You'll probably want the relevant RAID management tools to be installed and configured to report array status. This will likely be LSI's MegaCLI, but I'm not certain what OS you're running.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [entire category of RAID health checks on Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Storage-Systems/RAID-Controllers). Find the appropriate one for whatever controller and OS you're dealing with, and you probably have to install the vendor's CLI tools.